# Can sqoop write data to hive and hbase together

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, sqoop

Can we wirte sqoop data to hive and hbase together in hadoop

I want to write sqoop to hive (rdbms) and hbase (NoSql) together

Comment: do you want to write a sqoop process to import data into hive (this is not a rdbms btw)  and hbase at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

No it cannot. If you want the data to show up in Hive and HBase, you will have to import it into two separate locations, Create hive table on one for use in Hive. On the second location you  will have to create an External Hive table with HBase SerDe properties.
[Integrating Hive and HBase](https://acadgild.com/blog/hive-hbase-integration). This link shall give you the steps required.